# Purge azure static web apps enterprise-grade edge (CDN) using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-cdn, azure-static-web-app, azure-front-door

I enabled enterprise-edge on my Azure Static Web Apps. Is there a way to purge the enterprise-edge cache using Azure CLI?

Comment: Can you share the script you have tried so far? @RICHARD

Comment: Have you tried with the `az afd endpoint purge` command. @RICHARD

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no direct support with CLI to purge the cache of static web apps according to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/enterprise-edge?view=azure-cli-latest#commands). As a workaround, follow one of the below ways to meet your requirement.

- Change the content of the file you want to delete. So that it changes and will trigger a new deployment and the CDN will cache the updated content.
- Deploying a new version of your static web app as it will cause the CDN to refetch the files and update its cache.
- Or if you want to remove the cache of a CDN end point which is linked to the static web app. To do so, use [`az afd endpoint purge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-endpoint-purge)CLI command.